# how to get first word before spacing from text file java?

Tags: java

how to get first word from list.txt? when i insert "45" will be searching and display "45 toyota camry"

this example of list.txt

```
45 toyota camry
26 honda jazz
13 honda accord
65 nissan bluebird
```

this my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String data = new String();

    File input = new File ("list.txt");
    String read = null;
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList()); 
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nEnter your code car : ");
    data =in.nextLine();
    Scanner typescan; // Not used
    BufferedReader filescan;

    filescan = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("list.txt"));
    String line = data;

    while((line = filescan.readLine()) != null) {    
        if(line.equals(data)) { 
            System.out.print(line);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sorry, could not find it.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String#startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)). For example,

```
boolean b = true; 
while((line = filescan.readLine()) != null) {    
    if(line.startsWith(data)) { 
        System.out.print(line);
        b = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(b)
    System.out.println("Sorry, Not found");
```

Comment: but when i insert 26 from list.txt he display "Sorry, could not find it." no display "26 honda jazz"

Comment: @NisaAhmad updated my code. Try it now. Make sure you do exactly as above.

Answer (score 0):

To read next token in file use java.util.Scanner instead of BufferedReader. Here is code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File input = new File ("C://foo.txt");
        String read = null;
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList()); 
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter your code car : ");
        String data = in.nextLine();
        Scanner typescan; // Not used
        Scanner filescan;

        filescan = new Scanner(input);
        String line = data;

        while(filescan.hasNext()) {
            line=filescan.next();
            if(line.equals(data)) { 
                System.out.print(line);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Sorry, could not find it.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Enter your code car : 45
45
```

Now scanner reads 45 but not entire line.

Comment: when i insert "26" no display "26 honda jazz".

Comment: you need to read line by line and use method startsWith to compare read line with your inpput 26.

Comment: i dont get it..how?

Comment: `while(filescan.hasNextLine()) {
            line=filescan.nextLine();
            if(line.startsWith(data)) {`

Comment: Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter your code car : ");
         data = in.nextLine();          
        Scanner typescan; // Not used
        Scanner filescan;

        filescan = new Scanner(input);
        String line = data;

        while(filescan.hasNext()) {
            line=filescan.nextLine();
            if(line.startsWith (data)) { 
                System.out.print(line);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Sorry, could not find it.");
                break;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read in your file into the variable `text` and obtained the number from the user in the variable `input` you may do it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "45 toyota camry\n" +
                  "26 honda jazz\n" +
                  "13 honda accord\n" +
                  "65 nissan bluebird";
    String input = "45";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(" + input + ".*)(\n.*)*").matcher(text);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```